# Partition /boot full regularly

Tags: boot, kernel

The boot partition is just under 500M (457M according to df -h)

When installing the third kernel, update-initramfs returns this error:
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block

And after that it is impossible to install a new kernel.

I don't install any kernel myself, I let the app-center take care of it. On the other hand I have to delete the old ones regularly. To do this, I use mainline.

Is this usual? Should app-center do the cleaning normally?
I have always had this problem.

Thank you for your help.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: Running into the same issue--have never manually installed a kernel, but my `/boot` partition is full and has stayed that way for weeks, resulting in OS update failures.  
  
I know how to delete old kernels manually, but it feels odd to have to given elementaryOS's ethos, particularly within 6 months of installing Odin.

Comment: On my side, looks like the problem was that all kernels were marked manually installed in APT. Upstream issue looks to be [this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/packagekit/+bug/1914278). Fix is going out with Ubuntu 22.04 but is unlikely to be backported, so we'll probably have to wait until OS 7.